# Elasticsearch needs to page reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, turbolinks, searchkick

My question is quite simple actually I followed the [tutorial here](https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch), and I made a dictionary sample. so after found the word with "searchkick" I click "clear" button and all javascript in the page disappears [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1lES32hXWr7b2d6RmVIemxGQ28/edit?usp=sharing).

Thank you very much

Comment: try to remove turbolinks

Comment: thanks knotito but is there any way to spesify the app/views which is use turbolinks and which is not instead of removing all ?
 Thank you

Comment: I found the solution i add `data: { no_turbolink: true }` in my `link_to "clear"`  tag Thanks

Comment: i wonder is there any other solution?

Comment: you can try jquery-turbolinks https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks which allow you to bind events